# Fading effect in CSS not working when the div closes

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

When i click on the toggle button and it hides the div, it closes abruptly without the fading animation. What am I going wrong?

I would like to hide the div with a fading effect too. What is being missed?

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; opacity: 1\9; /* IE9 only */ } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; opacity: 1\9; /* IE9 only */ } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; opacity: 1\9; /* IE9 only */ } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

.fade-in.one {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Toggle Foo</a>
   <div id="foo" style="display:none;" class="fade-in one">
      Here I am toggling the display text
   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'none')
          e.style.display = 'block';
       else
          e.style.display = 'none';
    }
//-->
  </script>
```

Comment: `display` is not an animatable or transitionable property.

Comment: Okay. Any other technique that you can think of to get this going? I simply want to toggle a div with a bit of animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have additional adjustments, let me know.

```js
function toggle(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id); 
    e.style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(function(){ e.classList.toggle('visible') }, 1);        
}


function transition(id){

    var el = document.createElement("temp"); 
    var transitions = {
      'transition':'transitionend'
    }

    for(t in transitions){
        if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener(transition("foo"), function() {
  if(!this.classList.contains("visible")) {
      this.style.display='none';
  }
});
```

```css
#foo.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}

#foo { 
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle('foo')" class="toggle">Toggle Foo</a>
<div id="foo">
  Here I am toggling the display text
</div>
```

Comment: Can we do without jquery but plain javascript? I'm not using any JS framework.

Comment: I just updated your code by adding more plain text in the div. Any solution to the blank space that is created?

Comment: Took some time, but here you are.